# How can I copy the last 20 rows of a canvas into another canvas by using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I wan't to copy the last and the first 20 rows of an image into two seperate canvas.
It is pretty easy to copy the opper 20 rows, but I'm having trouble with the lower rows.

Top Canvas:

```
    canvas_top.width = video.width;
    canvas_top.height = 20;
    var context_top = canvas_top.getContext('2d');
    context_top.drawImage(video, 0, 0, video.width, canvas_top.height);
```

The lower rows can't be copied that way because you can't enter an index.

What's an fast way to copy the some rows of an video into a new canvas?

My ideas so far:

fill the canvas with empty values and replace them with the original data:

```
for(var i=(frame_data.length)-bottom_delta;i<frame_data.length;i+=4){
        bottom_data.data[counter] = frame_data[i];
        bottom_data.data[counter+1] = frame_data[i+1];
        bottom_data.data[counter+2] = frame_data[i+2];
        bottom_data.data[counter+3] = frame_data[i+3];
        counter+=4;
        }

    context_bottom.putImageData(bottom_data,0,0);
```

This didn' work.

I tried to rotate the canvas, but it seems that when you rotate a canvas it won't change the position of the pixels within the array.

context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, video.width, video.height);
        context.scale(1,-1); 
        context.translate(0,-video.height);
        context_bottom.drawImage(contextcanvas, 0, 0, video.width, video.height);
        context.scale(1,-1); 
        context.translate(0,-video.height);

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use the “clipping” parameters of context.drawImage to grab the top & bottom lines**

```
    // clip the top 20 lines of the test canvas and put in upper canvas
    ctxU.drawImage(canvas,0,0, canvas.width,20,0,0,canvasU.width,canvasU.height);

    // clip th bottom 20 lines of the canvas and put in lower canvas
    ctxL.drawImage(canvas,0,canvas.height-20, canvas.width,20,0,0, canvas.width,20);
```

[image]

And then you can analyze the upper and lower canvases using getImageData:

```
var imgData = ctxU.getImageData(0,0, canvasU.width, canvasU.height);
var data = imgData.data;

// vertical rows
for(var y = 0; y < canvasU.height; y++) {
  // horizontal columns
  for(var x = 0; x < canvasU.width; x++) {
    var r = data[((canvasU.width * y) + x) * 4];
    var g = data[((canvasU.width * y) + x) * 4 + 1];
    var b = data[((canvasU.width * y) + x) * 4 + 2];
    var a = data[((canvasU.width * y) + x) * 4 + 3];

    // and then do your stuff with the rgba info

  }
}
// put the edited imgData back:
```

Here’s code and a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/66nJk/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; padding:30px; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    var canvasU=document.getElementById("upper");
    var ctxU=canvasU.getContext("2d");
    var canvasL=document.getElementById("lower");
    var ctxL=canvasL.getContext("2d");

    // make a test canvas
    var gradient=ctx.createLinearGradient(-50,0,canvas.width+50,canvas.height);
    gradient.addColorStop(0.25,"red");
    gradient.addColorStop(0.50,"green");
    gradient.addColorStop(0.75,"blue");
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    ctx.fillStyle=gradient;
    ctx.fill();


    // clip the top 20 lines of the test canvas and put in upper canvas
    ctxU.drawImage(canvas,0,0, canvas.width,20,0,0,canvasU.width,canvasU.height);
    // clip th bottom 20 lines of the canvas and put in lower canvas
    ctxL.drawImage(canvas,0,canvas.height-20, canvas.width,20,0,0, canvas.width,20);




}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="upper" width=300 height=20></canvas><br>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas><br>
    <canvas id="lower" width=300 height=20></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This *should* be trivial using `getImageData` and `putImageData`:

```
// get bottom 20 rows from source canvas
var data = src_ctx.getImageData(0, 0, src_ctx.canvas.width, 20);

// put them into the destination canvas
dst_ctx.putImageData(data, 0, 0);
```

Comment: this will take the first 20 rows, not the last ones :(